# SQL Server inserts a special string (space on the right) and exceeds the column size. Why not report an error?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, database

DB version：SQL Server 2016

```
--Create database
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test] ([a] nvarchar(3))

--Insert strings longer than 3 （Success and not report an error）
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;

INSERT INTO test VALUES('1            ');

--Query table results '1  ',Its length is 3.

SET ANSI_PADDING ON;

INSERT INTO test VALUES('1111111111');
--[Err] 22001 - [SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated.
```

According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016), said "Trailing blanks in character values inserted into varchar columns are not trimmed."

Who can tell me why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure the answer to your question. But I don't think your experiment is demonstrating exactly what you meant it to, because "[The ANSI padding] setting affects only the definition of new columns," not data inserted into existing columns (per your link).

Comment: Thank you. I'm just curious why there's no error in inserting an extra long string.And I don't know if the "ANSI_PADDING" switch is related.